# How to make custom DataGridViewComboBox dependent only on its DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: .net, winforms, events, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcombobox

Popular way ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/z0ccx01c(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx), [2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/1f41f16d-17a9-4c52-92cf-3de9426a2dd7/image-inside-datagridviewcomboboxcell)) 
for custom painting of items in **DataGridViewComboBox** is handling of event DataGridView1.**EditingControlShowing** and setting up DrawItem event handlers there:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(
    object sender,
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    theBoxCell = (ComboBox) e.Control;
    theBoxCell.DrawItem += theBoxCell_DrawItem;
    theBoxCell.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
}
```

You see what is wrong: it uses *control-level event* to handle work for columns. But what if I have 50+ datagridviews? Painting of custom combo boxes should be handled *per column instance*, leaving control level intact.

Minimal implementation of per-column handling is below. The only problem I have is that `OnDrawItem()` method is not getting called. What am I missing? (You can see that fuchsia background override from *the same* class is working.)

(To reproduce, just paste the following into class file and add column of type **DataGridViewCustomPaintComboBoxColumn** to your **DataGridView1**.)

```cs
public class DataGridViewCustomPaintComboBoxColumn : DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
    public DataGridViewCustomPaintComboBoxColumn()
    {
        base.New();
        CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCustomPaintComboBoxCell();
    }

}

public class DataGridViewCustomPaintComboBoxCell : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
{
    public override Type EditType {
        get { return typeof(DataGridViewCustomPaintComboBoxEditingControl); }
    }

    protected override void Paint(...)
    {
        //painting stuff for incative cells here - works well
    }

}

public class DataGridViewCustomPaintComboBoxEditingControl : DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl
{
    public override Color BackColor { // property override only for testing
        get { return Color.Fuchsia; }    // test value works as expected
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) // never called - why?
    {
        base.OnPaint(e)
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)  // never called - why?
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The only problem I have is that OnDrawItem() method is not getting called. What am I missing?*

What you see inside a focussed `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` is pretty much a 'real' `ComboBox` and you need a reference to it in order to hook into its `DrawItem` event! (You can have a look the Controls collection of the DGV to see that there is one more when a ComboBoxCell has focus..  `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` is directly descended from `ComboBox` )

**Note**: One difference to an out of the box `CombBox` is that is has set `DrawMode = OwnerDrawVariable` by default. If you want to replace it by something you create yourself, don't forget to set it in code!

**Looks like that is what you are missing!**

If you can create your own `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` and make it appear in your DGV you're all set.

---

An alternative model I often use is a sort of 'Decorator', that implements the custom drawing for all columns you register with it.

```
DgvCombBoxPainter.Register(DataGridView dgv, stringOrInt columnNameOrIndex..)
```

In the registration function it would hook into the necessary DGV methods, that is `EditingControlShowing` to get at the `ComboBox` you see, when the DGV has focus and the `CellPainting` for the other cases.

The decorator can be static and needs only one `ComboBox` for all columns you have registered, as only one can have focus at a time..

If you can handle all painting code in the decorator all the better. From the events it can always reach back to the `DataGridView` via `sender` and the cells' properties via the `DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs` parameter..

You can even put a reference to the current cell into the `ComboBox` reference's `Tag`:

```
theBoxCell.Tag = dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
```

If you want you could also provide individual delegates to call in the paint event(s) when registering. You would then have to keep a list of those, maybe in a Dictionary..

Comment: I understand your static decorator idea but before accepting the answer, I'm not sure about your reasoning. Exactly as you say, `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` is not a Control. It is used to paint replicas of the control in inactive cells (and serve single control instance to edited cell). So overriding its `OnPaint()` event works as expected (I extended the above source). OTOH `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` *is* a Control (direct descendant of `ComboBox`) so when its instance is created for use with `EditingControlShowing` event, its overridden `OnPaint()` and `ItemDraw()` should work, no?

Comment: Yes, I think you got that all right, except that I'm not sure the Paint/OnPaint events will take effect or even fire; they are replaced by the DrawItem/OnDrawItem event. To draw the portion that is not dropped you need to check for `e.Index == -1`.

Comment: At the moment I'm not sure if we are thinking the correct way. I need to reaffirm. My points: First : [reference source for DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.cs](http://bit.ly/1Ojc1Zl) does *not* show any manipulation with its `ComboBox` precedessor.(No disabling of painting stuff etc.) Second: Overriding `OnPaint()` and `OnDrawItem()` does *not* work even with standard plain `ComboBox`. So maybe after discovering how to correctly create custom-painted combobox, no decorator might be required – just a properly written descendant of `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` :). Let me check that...

Comment: _Overriding OnPaint() and OnDrawItem() does not work even with standard plain ComboBox_. Hm, OnPaint I would not expect to work, it doesn't even show in the designer or Intellisense . But OnDrawItem?? (You did set its DrawMode to some OwnerDrawXxx ?)

Comment: I forgot setting DrawMode! It seems it solves it all :) `OnDrawItem()` is getting called now so I can do whatever I need.  Make this your answer and I will accept that. Perhaps forget all that stuff with static decorator, it has no added value for custom painting. So I'll accept your answer saying: just add `DrawMode = Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` (or `OwnerDrawVariable`) into `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` constructor.

Comment: done. I still like to use decorators, as they can plug into any control so easily, especially when added a little late in the developement process ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83514/discussion-between-miroxlav-and-taw).